# Adding a dummy identifier to data that varies by position and value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a project in SQL Server with diagnosis codes and a patient can have up to 4 codes but not necessarily more than 1 and a patient cannot repeat a code more than once. However, codes can occur in any order. My goal is to be able to count how many times a Diagnosis code appears in total, as well as how often it appears in a set position.

My data currently resembles the following:

| PtKey | Order # | Order Date | Diagnosis1 | Diagnosis2 | Diagnosis3 | Diagnosis 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | 1527 | 7/12/20 | J44.9 | R26.2 | NULL | NULL |
| 367 | 1679 | 7/12/20 | R26.2 | H27.2 | G47.34 | NULL |
| 325 | 1700 | 7/12/20 | G47.34 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 327 | 1710 | 7/12/20 | I26.2 | J44.9 | G47.34 | NULL |

I would think the best approach would be to create a dummy column here that would match up the diagnosis by position. For example, Diagnosis 1 with A, and Diagnosis 2 with B, etc.

My current plan is to rollup the diagnosis using an unpivot:
UNPIVOT ( Diag for ColumnALL IN (Diagnosis1, Diagnosis2, Diagnosis3, Diagnosis4)) as unpvt

However, this still doesn’t provide a way to count the diagnoses by position on a sales order.

I want it to look like this:

| Diagnosis | Total Count | Diag1 Count | Diag2 Count | Diag3 Count | Diag4 Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J44.9 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| R26.2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| H27.2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| I26.2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| G47.34 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot using `apply` and aggregate:

```
select v.diagnosis, count(*) as cnt,
       sum(case when pos = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as pos_1,
       sum(case when pos = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as pos_2,
       sum(case when pos = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as pos_3,
       sum(case when pos = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as pos_4
from data d cross apply
     (values (diagnosis1, 1),
             (diagnosis2, 2),
             (diagnosis3, 3),
             (diagnosis4, 4)
     ) v(diagnosis, pos)
where diagnosis is not null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `UNPIVOT` to transform the columns into groupable entities:

```
SELECT Diagnosis, [Total Count] = COUNT(*), 
  [Diag1 Count] = SUM(CASE WHEN DiagGroup = N'Diagnosis1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  [Diag2 Count] = SUM(CASE WHEN DiagGroup = N'Diagnosis2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  [Diag3 Count] = SUM(CASE WHEN DiagGroup = N'Diagnosis3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  [Diag4 Count] = SUM(CASE WHEN DiagGroup = N'Diagnosis4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM #x UNPIVOT (Diagnosis FOR DiagGroup IN 
    ([Diagnosis1],[Diagnosis2],[Diagnosis3],[Diagnosis4])) up
) AS x GROUP BY Diagnosis;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a300629d98139c4ea55e0679c9047d74)

Answer (score 1):

You can also manually unpivot via `UNION` before doing the conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Diagnosis, COUNT(*) As Total Count
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Position = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [Diag1 Count]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Position = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [Diag2 Count]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Position = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [Diag3 Count]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Position = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [Diag4 Count]
FROM
(
    SELECT PtKey, Diagnosis1 As Diagnosis, 1 As Position
    FROM [MyTable]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PtKey, Diagnosis2 As Diagnosis, 2 As Position
    FROM [MyTable]
    WHERE Diagnosis2 IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PtKey, Diagnosis3 As Diagnosis, 3 As Position
    FROM [MyTable]
    WHERE Diagnosis3 IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PtKey, Diagnosis4 As Diagnosis, 4 As Position
    FROM [MyTable]
    WHERE Diagnosis4 IS NOT NULL
) d
GROUP BY Diagnosis
```

Borrowing Aaron's fiddle, to avoid needing to rebuild the schema from scratch, and we get this:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d1f7f525e175f0f066dd1749c49cc46d